# Dagger 2 Inject annotation breaks the injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using dagger 2 to inject FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction into my Activity. 
Everything looks fine up to the point I add

```
@Inject
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Inject
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction
```

into my activity which throws an error on rebuild as below:

> Error:(21, 10) error: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager is injected at
>   com.toranj.tyke.ui.MainActivity.fragmentManager
>   com.toranj.tyke.ui.MainActivity is injected at
>   com.toranj.tyke.dagger.components.LotteryComponent.inject(activity)

Here is the **module**:

```
@Module
public class FragmentModule {

    FragmentActivity activity;

    public FragmentModule(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public FragmentManager providesFragmentManager() {
        return activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public FragmentTransaction providesFragmentTransaction() {
        return activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    }
}
```

Here is the **component**:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = FragmentModule.class)
public interface FragmentComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction();
}
```

and here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Inject
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentComponent fragmentComponent = DaggerFragmentComponent.builder()
                .fragmentModule(new FragmentModule(this))
                .build();
        fragmentComponent.inject(this);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to using dagger and dependency inject and I probably missed a point somewhere up there. Any answer with explanation would help me to understand injection and also is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** All the fragmentManagers used in the module, component and the activity are from **android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager**.

Comment: You must use the same FragmentManager in Activity, Component and Module, check the packages.

Comment: @IsmaelDiVita they are all from android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager package

Comment: Any chance you are injecting an activity with another component? it looks like so from the error: LotteryComponent.java

Answer (score 1):

I guess `android.app.FragmentManager` is used in `FragmentComponent`.

`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` should be used instead.

Comment: I double checked and all the FragmentManagers are from android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the error, it seems that you are using another component to inject the activity: `LotteryComponent.java`

Also, try changing this method

```
@Provides
@PerActivity
public FragmentTransaction providesFragmentTransaction() {
    return activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
}
```

to

```
@Provides
@PerActivity
public FragmentTransaction providesFragmentTransaction(FragmentManager fm) {
    return fm.beginTransaction();
}
```

I doubt this will solve the problem but it's worth a shot, at least you will be retrieving the object consistently from the same source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should inject the class that you actually want to use.

```
public interface FragmentComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);
}
```

This will inject `Activity`, which is part of the Android Framework and does not have any `@Inject` annotated fields. This inject method will basically be a no-op.

Dagger generates the dependency graph at *compile time*. It does not know that you suddenly try to inject `MainActivity` and expect `FragmentManager` to appear.

### tl;dr

Provide a

```
public interface FragmentComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. That's actually true what you said here but unfortunately changing the activity type to MainActivity did not fix the issue. Could it be the type of activity that I'm passing to my module be the issue?

Comment: Also changing the FragmentActivity in the fragmentModule's constructor to AppcompatActivity didn't fix it